# Unhandled Exception: ImageException: EOF reached without finding string terminator

Tags: flutter, dart

Getting this error after clicking 4 times the button that calls the rotateImage() function.

E/flutter (21064): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: ImageException: EOF reached without finding string terminator

E/flutter (21064): #0 InputBuffer.readString package:image/…/util/input_buffer.dart:130

E/flutter (21064): #1 new ExifAsciiValue.data package:image/…/exif/exif_value.dart:158

E/flutter (21064): #2 ExifData._readEntry package:image/…/exif/exif_data.dart:654

E/flutter (21064): #3 ExifData.read.<anonymous closure> package:image/…/exif/exif_data.dart:598

My code:

```
Future<dynamic> rotateImage() async {
    List<int> imageBytes = List<int>.from(bytes!);
    final originalImage = img.decodeImage(imageBytes);
    img.Image newImage;
    newImage = img.copyRotate(originalImage!, 90);
    final fixedFile = await widget.file.writeAsBytes(img.encodeJpg(newImage));
    Uint8List tempBytes = fixedFile.readAsBytesSync();
    setState(() {
      bytes = tempBytes;
    });
    return tempBytes;
  }
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: No, I just ended up not using this method.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was within the Image library.

It should be fixed in version 4.0.12 and above if i remember correctly. I had the issue and now it works.